# how to set asynchronize_session to false for on_duplicate_key_update in sqlalchemy with mysql database in bulk insert?

Tags: python, mysql, async-await, sqlalchemy, bulkinsert

i have a query in `sqlalchemy` like this:

```
insert_clause = insert(db_model).values([{key: values}, ...])

on_duplication_clause = insert_clause.on_duplicate_key_update(
    insert_clause.inserted,
)
await session.excecute(on_duplication_clause)
await session.commit()
```

it works fine in many cases with sync session and I didn't encounter any error with async session until now.

after trying to bulk insert, i get this error:

```
ERROR:root:Could not evaluate current criteria in Python: "Cannot evaluate AsBoolean with operator <function is_true at 0x7f04c2228940>". Specify 'fetch' or False for the synchronize_session execution option.
```

i tried to set it to like this:

```
await session.execute(on_duplication_clause.execution_options(synchronize_session=False))
```

and also:

```
await session.execute(on_duplication_clause.execution_options(synchronize_session='fetch'))
```

but it didn't work.
i also tried this:

```
on_duplication_clause = insert_clause.on_duplicate_key_update(
    inserted=insert_clause.inserted,
    synchronize_session=False,
)
```

but i got another error that i should not put `asynchornize_session` in `on_duplicate_key_update`

```
packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/session.py", line 214, in execute
compose-wcapi_service-1  |     result = await greenlet_spawn(
compose-wcapi_service-1  |   File "/src/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 115, in greenlet_spawn
compose-wcapi_service-1  |     result = context.switch(*args, **kwargs)
compose-wcapi_service-1  |   File "/src/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1705, in execute
compose-wcapi_service-1  |     bind = self.get_bind(**bind_arguments)
compose-wcapi_service-1  | TypeError: get_bind() got an unexpected keyword argument 'synchronize_session'
```

is there a way to solve this issue?